# Can I use my company name instead of using ofbiz logo and name

Tags: ofbiz

Sorry this is not a programming questions. My company is looking to do some work on ofbiz. I read the license of apache and I am not sure if its legal to change the logo to our company logo.

http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN

Comment: This question perhaps belongs to [the Programmers SE site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can. There is nothing preventing you from that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Visual Studio Code to edit the java and html code and SVG editor such Adobe Photo shop to edit the logo.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. They are asking about the legality of changing the logo, not requesting tools to edit the logo.